# Change jquery slider to slide down then slide up old section

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, tabs, slider

Okay, long story short, what I am trying to do is change the jquery around to have the new section populate slide down on top of the old div, and then slide up the old div, to make only the new content box appear.  as of right now, the code works perfectly sliding up the old section, and then sliding down the new content.

Code Sample for The Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function doTab() {
        $(".active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(".content").slideUp();
        var content_show = $(this).attr("title");
        $("#"+content_show).slideDown();
    }

    // When a link is clicked
    $("a.tab").click(doTab);

    if (window.location.hash) {
        $('a[title="' + window.location.hash.substring(2) + '"]').click();
    }
});
```

Code for the tabs and sections

```
<ul id="tabs">
    <li><a href="#" title="type1" class="tab active">type1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="type2" class="tab">type2</a></li>
</ul>

<!--<div class="dpoint-holder"><div class="dpoint"></div></div>-->
<section id="type1" class="content">
    <p>contents1contents1contents1contents1contents1</p>
</section>
<section id="type2" class="content content_2">
    <p>contents2contents2contents2contents2</p>
</section>
```

Comment: Define "pointer". I have no idea what it means as you're using it. It also doesn't help that you seem to be using the term in two different contexts in your question.

Comment: I apologize, pointer refers to a sliding jpg roughly 20x20 which is defined as a background image for .dpoint , so the $.dpoint.css.etc  portion of the javascript refers to the pointer div in the html acting as a divider of the tabs-"pointer"-content section